# How do you fix animation not triggering on hover?

Tags: html, css

I have a hover animation for a button but it doesn't seem to trigger.

Button:

```
<button class="submit-button">Send</button>
```

The css:

```
.submit-button {
  background: transparent;
  border: 3px solid #edc27b;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 25px 80px;
  position: relative;
  color: #edc27b;
  font-family: "baron-neue-regular", "Helvetica", "Arial" !important;
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.submit-button::after {
  content: '';
  height: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
  width: 100%;
  background: #101010;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
}

.submit-button:hover::after{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

What it's supposed to do is trigger another recktangle (the ::after pseudo class) to transition in from the middle across the button. This one is rotated 45 degrees so that the corners appear to be cut. I can't figure out what the problem might be.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or stackblitz please

Comment: you are only changing opacity on hover so nothing will move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, thanks to Temani Afif I figured out that I never changed the movement, only the opacity

Before:

```
.submit-button:hover::after{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

After:

```
.submit-button:hover::after{
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.3s;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%) rotate(45deg);
  opacity: 1;
}
```